# How to create a update function in LINQ when object has a list?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I´m still having a hard time with Linq.
I need to write a Update Function tat receives an object that has a list. Actually, A region has a list of cities. I want to pass an object  "Region" that has a name filed and a list of cities. The problem, is the city objects came from another context and I am unable to attach them to this context. I have been trying several functions, and always get an error like "EntitySet was modified during enumeration" or other. I am tring to make the code below work, but if anyone has a different approach please help.

```
    public int Updateregion(region E)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new AppDataDataContext())
            {
                var R =
                       (from edt in ctx.regiaos
                        where edt.ID == E.ID
                        select edt).SingleOrDefault();              
                if (R != null)
                {
                    R.name = R.name;
                    R.description = E.description;
                }
                R.cities = null;
                R.cities.AddRange(Edited.Cities);
                ctx.SubmitChanges();
                return 0 //OK!
            }
        }
        catch (Exception  e)
        {
            ......
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you guys need some incentive ? I´ll gladly s-mail a kg of brazilian gourmet coffee to the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't attach objects retrieved from one datacontext to another, it's not supported by Linq-to-SQL. You need to somehow dettach the objects from their original context, but this isn't supported either. One can wonder why a dettach method isn't available, but at least you can fake it by mapping the list to new objects:

```
var cities = Edited.Cities.Select(city => new City {
    ID = city.ID,
    Name = city.Name,
    /* etc */
});
```

The key here is to remember to map the primary key and NOT map any of the relation properties. They must be set to null. After this, you should be able to attach the new cities list, and have it work as expected.

Comment: AHM,I tried this and it works, but it looks a lot more trouble than it is worth because it takes huge amounts of code. If I have to do this I´m better off with ADO. Is there any other way ?

Comment: As far as I know, it is the only way to dettach entities from contexts, but I agree its is bothersome. If you don't want to do this, you have to find some way to get the objects from the same context - but that can mess up your repositorypatterns, and that is not ideal either.

Comment: Maybe you could use AutoMapper to make the mappings simpler, but you would need to configure it to skip relationproperties so that isn't super great either. But at least you would have the configration in one place....

Comment: I'll try that this afternoon. I checked the MSDN samples and not one of them addresses this issue. Microsoft does not know how to do it either. Is anyone from MS around ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's not so much a matter of Microsoft not knowing how to do it - they just don't think it's appropriate to do it. The pattern that Linq-to-SQL is based around is called unit of work, and a datacontext represent a single task being performed.

You are not supposed to take objects belonging to one task and use them in another. Microsoft believes that is breaking the pattern, and therefore it's not supported.

Comment: AHM, you´re right. It makes Linq a lot less fun to use though.